# How can I quicksort this array by something other than the first character?

Tags: python, arrays, csv, quicksort

Here is my code:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000000)
 
def partition(arr, low, high):
    i = (low-1)         # index of smaller element
    pivot = arr[high]     # pivot
 
    for j in range(low, high):
 
       
        if arr[j] <= pivot:
            i = i+1
            arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]

    arr[i+1], arr[high] = arr[high], arr[i+1]
    return (i+1)

def quickSort(arr, low, high):
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return arr
    if low < high:
 
       
        pi = partition(arr, low, high)
        quickSort(arr, low, pi-1)
        quickSort(arr, pi+1, high)
 
path = 'C:/Users/razzb/Desktop/quicksort/Dateset1.csv'
file_CSV = open(path,'r')   
data_CSV = csv.reader(file_CSV)
arr= list(data_CSV)
arr2= list(data_CSV)
n = len(arr)
quickSort(arr, 0, n-1)
print("Sorted array is:")
for i in range(n):
    print(arr[i]),
```

Essentially, if my Array is [['1,8,3'],['2,4,1']] I want to quicksort the array on based on that 3rd number in there. The output should be

['2,4,1']
['1,8,3']

right now its

['1,8,3']
['2,4,1']

Comment: Please read  up on a minimal example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: A common way to program scripts in Python is to print output from any new line. So do use print statements.

Comment: Also it would be helpful if you didn't use data from a file but a list that you include with the code. It would make it much easier for people to help you debug it.

Comment: Why not use native `sort`?